# Add svg fill patterns dynamically via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to dynamically add an SVG fill pattern to an SGV file after loading it, but even though inspecting code it appears there, I can't see it in the resulting image.

`document.getElementById('svg').prepend('<pattern id="pat"><image href="test.jpg"/></pattern>');`

It works if I hard code the pattern in the file, but I need to do it dynamically.

Comment: `'<pattern id="pat"><image href="test.jpg"/></pattern>'` is a string. That’s not useful. You need an actual `<pattern>` node. Use [`createElementNS`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) to create the SVG nodes. Alternatively, you could try [`insertAdjacentHTML`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

Comment: Note: the arguments and API of [`before`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/before), [`prepend`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend), [`append`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/append), and [`after`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/after) are identical.